# random forests: Does it make any difference if the test-set is also labeled?

Tags: r, random-forest, supervised-learning

All the examples I can find of making predictions using random forests already have the actual answers (i.e. the test-set has labels). What do you do when you don't have that column?

For example, this tutorial uses the iris data: http://mkseo.pe.kr/stats/?p=220

If we were doing this for real, the test dataset would have columns [1,4] and not column 5. If you try to run this without column 5 it kicks up an error that the dataframes are not the same size, which, obviously they're not.

How do you make predictions when you don't already have a column of answers?

Edit
Clarification using excerpt from above link:

Prepare training and test set.

```
 test = iris[ c(1:10, 51:60, 101:110), ]
 train = iris[ c(11:50, 61:100, 111:150), ]
```

The test data frame has a complete species column. I'm trying to predict the species based on the forest I grow from the training set. So the position I am in is after running:

```
 test <- test[-5]
```

I'm now in the position I'd be in if I'd gone out and collected a bunch of plant measurements and wanted to know the species based on the tree model I've grown from my training data. So, how can I predict the Species column I've just deleted based on the remaining data in the test dataframe and the forest grown using the training dataframe?

Comment: Random forest is a classification algo falling in the category of *supervised learning*. You are looking for *unsupervised learning*, where "clustering" comes to mind.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not! I'm trying to achieve exactly what the guy is in the tutorial, grow the random forest on a training set and then predict on a test set. However, for obvious reasons, I don't have a column of predicted values already in place for my test set. I can grow the forest fine, I just can't work out how to make predictions.

Comment: Ah... Sorry I misunderstood.

Comment: We won't be able to help unless you can provide a reproducible example that illustrates the problem you're having. The `predict` function will not complain about missing the _response_ variable. So you're doing something else wrong, but how could we know what that is?

Comment: In real life when using a test set this one sometimes doesn't have yet the response column. This is common in Kaggle competition for example for obvious reason such as overfitting or data snooping. Therefore, you need to work with your "training" set and split it or use resampling techniques such as crossvalidation and co to find the right parameters. I'll suggest you to read a little about machine learning

Comment: The iris data is almost a perfect parallel. All that needs to be done to make it identical is after the two concatenations to prepare the test and training datasets, just test <- test[-5]

Comment: a reproducible example of what you did to get your error -- @flodel has clearly demonstrated that if you step through the example you linked to, your error message will not occur.

Comment: Ok your question was "Obviously the training-set must be labeled, but does it matter if the test-set is also labeled?" to which the answer is **"No"**. Any test-set labels just get ignored. (I'm completely retitling your question - 'new data' made me think 'he's looking for an algorithm to dynamically-recompute the RF based on streaming data'. The current title must be the most misleading title on all of SO!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although the tutorial you quote has the `Species` column in the `test` set, it is not needed by the `predict` function as you guessed:

```
library(randomForest)
test  <- iris[ c(1:10, 51:60, 101:110), -5]  # removed the Species column here.
train <- iris[ c(11:50, 61:100, 111:150), ]
r <- randomForest(Species ~., data=train, importance=TRUE, do.trace=100)
predict(r, test)
```

Comment: I must have had a typo floating around somewhere. I was on this for hours yesterday and now with your code it's fine. Can't see the difference! Thanx for going through it.